# In Vue 3 hook, in the return type object inside `this` is always `undefined`

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vue.js

Can anyone tell me, why in the code below, in the return block, `this` stays `undefined`?

```
export const useAutoSave = (
  cacheKey: string,
  interval: number,
  getSaveData: () => Omit<SaveDto, 'savedTime'>,
) => {
  let timer: any
  const { storage, reset } = useStorageObject<SaveDto>(
    SaveDto,
    'auto-save-' + cacheKey,
    false,
  )
  const save = () => {
   // ...
  }
  return {
    reset,
    getPrevSaved() {
      return storage
    },
    save,
    track() {
      console.log(this) // <-- why is `this` `undefined` here?
      this.disposer() // <-- reference error
      timer = setInterval(save, interval)
    },
    disposer() {
      clearInterval(timer)
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that function is in a module, [`this` is automatically bound to `undefined` by Babel](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/7636), leading to the errors you observed.

To get your code to work, `disposer` needs to be declared beforehand (like you've done with `save()`):

```js
export const useAutoSave = (
  cacheKey: string,
  interval: number,
  getSaveData: () => Omit<SaveDto, 'savedTime'>,
) => {
  let timer: any

  const disposer = () => {
    clearInterval(timer)
  }

  return {
    //...
    track() {
      disposer()
      timer = setInterval(save, interval)
    },
    disposer,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [functional components migration guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/functional-components.html#overview) and [Vue 3 functional components documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/render-function.html#functional-components).

You should pass `props` and `context` as arguments to the functional component.

```
const FunctionalComponent = (props, context) => {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Not in vue 3 setup scope, just in hook.